# unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in

Tags: kubernetes

I am using docker desktop v 4.11.0
and Kubernetes v1.24.2

while decoding secrets I am getting this error

waiting for deletion: running [kubectl --context docker-desktop get -f - --ignore-not-found -ojson]

- stdout: ""
- stderr: "unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"env":[{"name":"TMPDIR","value":"/tmp"},{"name":"POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}}

Comment: What's the object you're passing on stdin to `kubectl get -f -`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates it is having an issue with the Kubernetes YAML  manifest file that you are using to create Secret in Kubernetes.

Please check syntax errors and incorrect values;  Please check ‘kind’ field and if it is missing you need to add it and  to the YAML manifest as well; and then try to decode the secret.

Please check the official [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for further reference.

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually I am creating secret using 
kubectl create secret command and it is created successfully, but when trying to run it is throwing above error [TMPDIR is not even part of secret]

Comment: I guess you have created a secret that includes a reference to 'TMPDIR' which is not part of secret data. When you create a secret using ‘kubectl create secret’ you need to specify the type of secret and  provide the secret as key-value pairs or in file. Try recreating the secret without including the ‘TMDIR’ key in the secret data.